# Check if file exists in the upload file array

Tags: php, forms

I got form at frontend to submit stuff, wherein I need to check if file exists on submit.

Please note that the form submits **array of files**. It is failing the all logics I have been trying. Please notice the `upload[]` on second line of html.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" id="upload-form" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" multiple="true" name="upload[]">
<input type="submit" name="upload_attachments" value="UPLOAD">
<form>
```

**PHP**

```
if(!file_exists($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'].'/'.$FILES['upload']['name'])) {

   $upload_error = 'file is not set !'; 
   return; //stop further code execution 
   }else{

   //do further validation   

   }
```

The code above shows `'file is not set !'` in both cases, that is when I hit submit button without uploading a file and when I select to upload a file and hit the submit button.

What is happening here, am I even doing it right?

Basically I want to return a 'File Empty' message when someone hits the submit button without selecting a file to upload, and stop the further code execution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$_FILES[<key>]['tmp_name']` - contains file path on server

`$_FILES[<key>]['name']` - is just original file name

To address array of files `file[]` you need to fetch data by 
`$_FILES[<key>][<property>][<id>]`

try

```
if(!file_exists($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][0])) {
```

**Manuals**

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Answer (score 2):

You are appending tmp_name and name. That is not needed. Just check uploaded file name like;

```
if(empty($_FILES['upload']['name'])) {

   $upload_error = 'file is not set !'; 
   return; //stop further code execution 
}else{

   //do further validation   

}
```

or you can check file existence like;

```
if(!file_exists($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][0])) {

   $upload_error = 'file is not set !'; 
   return; //stop further code execution 
}else{

   //do further validation   

}
```

Your multiple file array format is like below;

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo.txt
            [1] => bar.txt
        )

    [type] => Array
        (
            [0] => text/plain
            [1] => text/plain
        )

    [tmp_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => /tmp/phpYzdqkD
            [1] => /tmp/phpeEwEWG
        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 456
        )
)
```

You can refer [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Comment: Second chunk - on hitting submit without file - shows the upload error but also the `Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in......line 4`. Hitting submit with file also gives the same result.

Comment: First chunk of your code - on hitting submit without file - is ignoring the if rule and goes to else rule, so no joy there. On hitting submit with the file - returns same result.

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL Your answer is completely invalid, check http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: @Huseyin BABAL Yes, that is why I put an emphasis on `upload[]` and array part in the question, that is probably why all my other logics have failed till now. Checking on your new answer.

Comment: Thanks @mleko.  @gurung I have made a mistake in my updated question. I have reverted to previous one. `Warning: file_exists() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in......line 4` error given because it must be `!file_exists($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][0])`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   if (empty($_FILES['upload']['name']))
   {
   // No file was selected for upload, your (re)action goes here
   }

  note: place this code above
   if(!file_exists($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'].'/'.$FILES['upload']['name'])) {
```

Comment: @Ezhil This does not take the array matter in consideration. But thanks for the effort. This is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use php's is_uploaded_file function.

Here's an excerpt from php's site about the function.

> For proper working, the function is_uploaded_file() needs an argument like $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], - the name of the uploaded file on the client's machine $_FILES['userfile']['name'] does not work.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php

Comment: I do not have a problem with function. Just how it handles the array input.