# Uploading files not triggered after form submit

Tags: php, file-upload

I copied a script I already wrote once, but now it seems it skips the if statement where it should handle the upload itself.

I did this and there is actualy a file attached to the `$files`:

```
$files = isset($_FILES['files']) ? $_FILES['files'] : false;
$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0] = isset($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0]) ? $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0] : false;

var_dump($files);
var_dump($_FILES['tmp_name']);
```

The rest of the form is working just fine. Here is the part it seems to skip:

```
if ((file_exists($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0])) || (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0]))) {

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['files']['name']); $i++) {

        $file_name  = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
        $file_tmp   = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $file_size  = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
        $file_error = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];

         if ($file_error === 0) {

            $directory = 'lib/files/uploads/tasks/projects/'. strtolower($project_id) .'';

            $full_directory = $directory . '/' . $file_name;

            $counter = 1;

            while ($file_exists($full_directory)) {

                $info = pathinfo($full_directory);

                $filename = $info['dirname'] . '/' . $file_name . '(' . $counter++ . ')' . '.' . $info['extension'];

            }

            echo $filename;
            die();

            if (!file_exists($directory)) {

                mkdir($directory, 0777, true);

            }

            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $filename);

            $file_path = $filename;

            $query4 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `projects_tasks_files` (`name`, `path`, `task_id`, `created_at`, `created_by`) VALUES (:name, :pathname, :task_id, :created, :creator)");
            $query4->execute(array(

                ':name'         =>      $file_name,
                ':pathname'     =>      $file_path,
                ':task_id'      =>      $new_task_id,
                ':created'      =>      date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                ':creator'      =>      $_SESSION['id']     

            ));

        }

    }

}
```

The form itself is looking like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button class="trigger-upload" type="button" role="link">Browse files...</button>
    <input type="file" name="files" id="files" multiple>
    <ul class="selected-files"></ul>
</form>
```

Comment: treat `name="files"` as an array `name="files[]"` and use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and make sure you did start the session, seeing you're using them.

Comment: That did the job. Now I know what made me ate my keyboard... Thanks!

Comment: Can I just ask: I made a check if the filename already exists in the directory. But it doesn't exist already, so the while loop is not running. How should I catch the filename if it doesn't exists?

Comment: You're welcome, glad to have helped (if you want an answer for that, let me know). *Thinking....* about your 2nd comment.

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't be fair answering my own question if I didn't found the solution...

Comment: You would need to first do an `if(exist)` rather than a `while(exist)`, as this translates to it already existing, rather than checking IF it exists ;-)

Comment: Have a look at this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/23930447/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/32906715/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this (as per my initial comment)

You need to treat `name="files"` as an array `name="files[]"` in order for PHP to iterate over the multiple files.

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Error reporting would have been of help here.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.